# Take shoot using camera in ICS

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

in my app, using Gingerbread, this piece of code works:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
```

But in ICS (I tried on different ROMs), using

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

returns null.

How can I make the first code work?

Thanks in advance

.

PS: I found this solution:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(dir, "avatar.jpeg")));
```

But if a device haven't a storage expansion? Plus I dont need to save the image.